# Two runners on same base

Tags: rules, baseball, officiating

[October 17, 2017 Chicago Cubs v Los Angeles Dodgers](http://www.espn.com/mlb/game?gameId=371017116), two Cubs runners occupied third base at the same time in the ninth inning. The Dodgers' third baseman tagged the second runner first, and then the first runner. The umpires called neither out. It did not seem that play was dead but apparently the umpires thought it was.

Please clarify the rule on this?

Answer (score 6):

As you can see from the [full play-by-play of the game](http://www.espn.com/mlb/playbyplay?gameId=371017116), the hit by Albert Almora Jr. was a ground-rule double. This is due to the [ground rule at Wrigley Field that any ball which lodges in the ivy is automatically a double](https://twitter.com/PWSullivan/status/656652072201224192/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chicagotribune.com%2Fsports%2Fcolumnists%2Fct-wrigley-field-ivy-appetite-for-baseballs-20151021-column.html), so the play was dead. The umpires were (as is almost always the case) completely correct.